# Find the maximum of $f(x)=x^{a-x}$ in terms of $a$

Tags: calculus

I know that when $a=0$ then $f(x)=x^{a-x}$ becomes $f(x)=x^{-x}$ which I can derive to get $f'(x)=(-x^{-x}\!\cdot\!\ln(x))+(-x^{-x})$.
Plugging in $1/e$ gives us zero and the maximum of $f(x)=x^{-x}$ is $1/e$. I’m not sure how to factor $a$ into this so that the maximum is based off of $f(x)=x^{a-x}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Lambert W function?

Comment: Have you tried writing $f$ as $f(x) = \dfrac{x^a}{x^{x}}$ and then differentiate using the quotient rule ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\log x^{a-x}=\frac{a}{x}-1-\log x=0$$  Now draw the graphs of $x\mapsto \log x$ and $x\mapsto 1-(a/x)$  and discuss the existence of  a solution of $1-(a/x)=-\log x$ in $x$ in terms of $a$. Hint: look for the minimum of $x\mapsto x+x\log x.$